# Help normalizing a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, normalization

I don't see how the author normalizes $u(r)=Asin(kr)$. From Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd edition, page 141-142:

[image]

My integral was 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}|A|^2 \sin^2(\frac{n\pi r}{a})r^2 \sin \theta drd\theta d\phi=1$$

Mathematica simplifies the integral (without the $A$ for simplicity) to 
$$=\int_0^{\infty}4\pi r^2 \sin^2(\frac{n\pi r}{a})dr$$

but it stops there. I don't think this integral converges. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: This is not how you should calculate the normalization factor. Be careful $R(r)$ is your wave function, not u(r)

Comment: Well $R(r)=u(r)/r$, so in my mathematica integral I just change the $r^2 \to r$. However, this integral still doesn't converge.

[Screenshot of mathematica](http://imgur.com/a/jBiqW)

Comment: Still wrong. You should normalize the wave function squared: $R^2$. This will give you the infinite square well as the book says.

Comment: Ok I see my mistake in my last comment, but the integral still doesn't converge. The integral becomes $\int_0^{\infty} |A|^2 \sin^2 (n\pi r/a)$. What am I missing?

Comment: The integral doesn't go to infinity. Please, look at your boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to normalise $u(r)$.

What is $u(r)$ if $r>a$?

Are you sure about your upper limit for $r$ in your normalisation integral?